# TypeScript Async/Await Arrow Function: Right Syntax (in React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an arrow function, which compares two values.
One value comes from another function, which gets the value from an API Endpoint.
I would like to use the await / async style instead of Promises (.then, .catch, .finaly).

In JavaScript it's easy peasy, but I have some Problems with TypeScript. How to correctly write that function?

I have something like this (Pseudocode):

```
compareValues: Promise<boolean> = async () => {
   try {
      const value1 = false;
      const value2 = this.getValue2;

      const isEqual = (await value2) === value1;
      return isEqual;
   } catch (error) {
      throw error;
   }
}
```

```
getValue2 = async () => {
try {
   const value2 = await axios.get(url, config);
   const value2Data = await value2.data;

   return value2Data;
} catch (error) {
   throw error;
}
```

```
export interface IInterface {
   compareValues: () => Promise<boolean>;
}
```

```
const initialState: IInterface = {
   compareValues: () => {
      return Promise.resolve(false);
   }
}
```

With that code the IDE cries for the first line: *Type '() => Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]* 
While the compiler tells: *Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type '() => Promise'.
Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(): Promise'.  TS2322*

I have the feeling my return type is wrong...

Will the code wrap my `isEqual` value in a Promise?
Can I avoid that both functions are async?
What would be the right **Syntax**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `compareValues: Promise<boolean>` should be `compareValues: () => Promise<boolean>` - after all `compareValues` holds a *function* that will produce a promise *when called*. It's not an actual promise right now. If you instead need the promise itself, then you need to call the function.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem!
I just changed `compareValues: Promise<boolean> = async () => {` to `compareValues = async () => {` and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VLAZ found the error and explained it well in the comments.
I still wanted to post a version with the new changes.

I changed the first block of code to:

```
compareValues: = async () => {
   try {
      const value1 = false;
      const value2 = this.getValue2;

      const isEqual = (await value2) === value1;
      return isEqual;
   } catch (error) {
      throw error;
   }
}
```

Reason (explained in the comments): compareValues holds a function that will produce a promise *when called*. It's not an actual Promise itself.